# ¿Error al convertir fecha con formato 201801?

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente método en C#, el cual transforma las fechas de este formato: 201801 a este formato: 01/01/2018 - 15/01/2018 la cual divide el mes en 15 días, pero el detalle aquí es que cuando pongo 201824 me tira el siguiente error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Ejemplo de uso del método es:

```
y = Quincena_Fecha("201824");
```

Supongo que es un error porque sobrepasa los días del año, soy nuevo en esto así que me gustaría que me apoyaran con esto.

Cabe aclarar que el formato de fecha 201824 me refiero a que se divide así:

2018: año
24: quincena en curso

La cual tendría que transformarla en el siguiente formato: 01/12/2018 - 15/12/2018 pero me manda el error que ya menciono en la imagen.

```
public string Quincena_Fecha(string text)
{
    int Año;
    int.TryParse(text.Substring(0, 4), out Año);
    int Mes;
    int Quincena;
    if (int.TryParse(text.Substring(4, 2), out Quincena))
    {
        double Valor = ((double)Quincena / 2);

        Mes = System.Convert.ToInt32((Quincena + 1) / 2);

        if (Valor == System.Convert.ToInt32(Quincena / 2))
        {
            return "16/" + Mes.ToString("00") + "/" + Año + " - " + Convert.ToDateTime("01/" + (Mes + 1).ToString("00") + "/" + Año).AddDays(-1).ToString("dd") + "/" + Mes.ToString("00") + "/" + Año;
        }
        else
        {
            return "01/" + Mes.ToString("00") + "/" + Año + " - " + "15/" + Mes.ToString("00") + "/" + Año;
        }
    }
    else
        return "";
}
```

Comment: Fernando estas enviando el string de dia 201824 a uno de que corresponde a mes

Comment: Hola, mira la cuestión es la siguiente: 2018 me refiero al año y por ejemplo al 24 me refiero a la quincena que sería del 16/12/2018 - 31/12/2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema realmente se presenta en esta línea:

```
return "16/" + Mes.ToString("00") + "/" + Año + " - " + Convert.ToDateTime("01/" + (Mes + 1).ToString("00") + "/" + Año).AddDays(-1).ToString("dd") + "/" + Mes.ToString("00") + "/" + Año;
```

El error se basa específicamente a que estás haciendo una conversión a `DateTime` no válida, además que no es necesario sumar uno al mes ya que cuando sea el mes 12 te enviará un error, por eso deberá quedar la línea de la siguiente manera. Nota que para obtener el último día del mes se realiza con el método `DateTime.DaysInMonth(Año, Mes)`, enviando como parámetros el año y el mes, con esto ya no necesitas restar días o sumar meses:

```
return "16/" + Mes.ToString("00") + "/" + Año + " - " + new DateTime(Año, Mes, DateTime.DaysInMonth(Año, Mes)).ToString("dd") + "/" + Mes.ToString("00") + "/" + Año;
```

El código completo quedaría de la sigueinte manera:

```
public static string Quincena_Fecha(string text)
{
    int Año;
    int.TryParse(text.Substring(0, 4), out Año);
    int Mes;
    int Quincena;
    if (int.TryParse(text.Substring(4, 2), out Quincena))
    {
        double Valor = ((double)Quincena / 2);

        Mes = System.Convert.ToInt32((Quincena + 1) / 2);

        if (Valor == System.Convert.ToInt32(Quincena / 2))
        {
            return "16/" + Mes.ToString("00") + "/" + Año + " - " + new DateTime(Año, Mes, DateTime.DaysInMonth(Año, Mes)).ToString("dd") + "/" + Mes.ToString("00") + "/" + Año;
        }
        else
        {
            return "01/" + Mes.ToString("00") + "/" + Año + " - " + "15/" + Mes.ToString("00") + "/" + Año;
        }
    }
    else
        return "";
}
```

El resultado quedaría de la ejecución anterior sería:

> 16/12/2018 - 31/12/2018

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Quedó completa la función :)

Comment: @FernandoRumbo en C# no se llaman funciones, se llaman Métodos ;) Me alegra que te haya servido

Comment: Soy nuevo en esto, muchas gracias. Cada día se aprende algo nuevo :)